# Why <> operator is not allowed for source below 1.7?

Tags: java

in a java program , I have the following line of code :

```
HashMap<String, String> query_args = new HashMap<>();
```

and i receive the following error:

'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7

I tried to change the project compliance and jre to 1.7 but then eclipse could not resolve the imports. I am using jre 1.6.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Regarding `"Why <> operator is not allowed for source below 1.7"` -- because it was defined in Java 1.7. Kind of a silly question actually. A possible solution: upgrade your Eclipse to allow 1.7. If your question is more about why the error message, then your title should reflect this.

Comment: *reopen vote* it's only a silly question if you have a sense of what features were added in what versions of Java :/ people do have to learn that languages evolve at some point in their career, and this question perfectly well teaches that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Prior to Java 7 (1.7 here), you needed to do

```
HashMap<String, String> query_args = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Its referred to as the diamond operator, and is not backwards-compatible with earlier versions of Java.

Comment: Poorly asked question; excellent answer.  Way to read a mind!

Answer (score 10):

Because that wasn't introduced until Java 7.  I really don't know how else to answer that question, besides chronicling the history of Java.

Regarding imports, you should research why Eclipse cannot resolve whichever imports they are when set to Java 1.7, and if needed post that as a separate question.